# iOS 12.4 is missing in Xcode 11 GM

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode11

I have installed Xcode 11 GM and can't find iOS 12.4.1 simulator anymore. iOS 12.4.1 was installed in Xcode 10.3, but it is not available in Xcode 11 for some reason (not only iOS 12.4 - other simulators are also missing). Moreover, I can't download it via "Add Additional Simulators..." - the latest one available is 12.2. Any ideas why so and how to fix? 
Thanks!

Comment: I have the same issue with the final Xcode 11.0 release, too.

Comment: @balazs630 did you resolve the issue?

Comment: @ tyegah123 No.. I'd rather use the iOS 12.2 simulator for now. However the copy paste magic (the accapted answer) seems to work for others. I don't like the idea of changing Xcode.app files, who knows.. it may cause strange behaviour, evil bugs later.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

iOS 12.4 simulator files can be found in the Xcode 10.3 app bundle. While you can't download it from within Xcode (at the moment), you can simply copy them to the folder where additional simulators are usually installed. Go to the following subfolder, it is located inside Xcode.app (10.3):

```
Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes
```

and copy the `iOS.simruntime` package to here:

```
/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes
```

Rename `iOS.simruntime` to `iOS 12.4.simruntime`.

Restart Xcode 11.

Comment: you said "at the moment". Is this a know issue from Apple? is this intended?

Comment: @AndreiMatei I don't know. I only said it because things may change in the future

Comment: Thanks a lot, Deej! 

Comment: Just ran into this today, how is this possible?

Comment: At first it didn't work. I was getting "The operation couldn’t be completed. Invalid argument" when trying to create the simulator, although I had restarted my XCode. 
I had to restart my mac for it to work :)

Answer (score 8):

The 12.4 simulator is now available (in Xcode 11.1 at least):

[image: Screenshot]